# Interpreting fully connected layer in convolutional Neural network architecture

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to interpret this neural network architecture

3×3×32 Convolutional
2×2 MaxPool
Dropout
3×3×64 Convolutional
2×2 MaxPool
Dropout
Flatten
1 × 128 Full connected
Dropout
128 × 10 Fully connected
Softmax

i am confused here 1 × 128 Full connected and 128 × 10 Fully connected  what does it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using the flattening operation, the output will be (None, x)

Next in the 128 node fully connected(FC) layer, x is passed through each of the 128 neurons (nodes)

Finally, each of the 128 node's output are passed to 10 node FC layer with softmax activation

Here is a visualization, hope it helps

[image: Similar Architecture]